# How to write like query for date in java

Tags: java, date

Here I am going to get data based on date only but my data continence both date and time here I am using like query to select that data based on date but I am not getting it can any plz exp line it thanks.

```
String device = "NR09G05635";
String date = "2013-11-29";
java.util.Date temp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(date);
java.sql.Date date1 = new java.sql.Date(temp.getTime());
sql = "select * from gpsdata1 where  deviceId=? and dateTime like '" + date1 + "'";
System.out.println("sql" + sql);
ps1 = con.prepareStatement(sql);
ps1.setMaxRows(1);
ps1.setString(1, device);
ps1.execute();
rs = ps1.getResultSet();
```

Comment: what is happening..what is the i/p.. what is expected o/p??.. what is the o/p you are getting?.. "Not getting it" - a very generalized term bro..

Comment: you have to use statement or prepared statement if you want to pass the date object. Otherwise in your case you can pass string itself for example instead of "date1" you can pass "date".

Comment: Why are you combining PreparedStatement format and Statement format in your query?

Comment: sorry i want to get data based on date but in my datetime column will have both date and time .

Comment: Take a deep breath and elaborate your question a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

-You use the LIKE operator to compare a character, string, or CLOB value to a pattern. Case is significant. LIKE returns the BOOLEAN value TRUE if the patterns match or FALSE if they do not match

- Use TO_CHAR to explicitly create a string based on a DATE, using the format you want. Don't rely on implicit conversions.

Select  * 
From      gpsdata1 
Where       NVL ( TO_CHAR ( dateTime
                      , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM'
                )
         , ' '     -- One space
         ) Like '%';

Comment: A really bad solution, as using the "LIKE" operator is likely to cause a full table scan for a query. It is way better to calculate the desired interval for the date in question, and then make a select based on that: `... (dateTime >= t0) AND (dateTime < t1) ...`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM gpsdata1 
WHERE deviceId=? and  CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), dateTime, 126) LIKE '2013-11-19%'
```

LIKE operator does not work against `DATETIME` variables, but you can cast the `DATETIME` to a `VARCHAR`